# React bootstrap web won't loaded when added with navigation component for routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-router

Hello guys so I'm trying to create a web app using react-bootstrap and use BrowserRouter to link each of the component I have. I already wrap the index JS with BrowserRouter and I already add the Switch and Route tag to the navigation component, but when I tried to implement the navigation into app.js the web start to load endlessly without showing anything. Can anyone please help me with it ?

here is my navigation code:

```
import React from 'react'
import Facilities from './Facilities'
import Room from './Room'
import Booking from './Booking'
import Contact from './Contact'
import App from '../App'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

const Navigation = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/facilities">
                    <Facilities/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/room">
                    <Room/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/contactus">
                    <Contact/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/bookingRoom">
                    <Booking/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/">
                    <App/>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </>
    )
}

export default Navigation
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `App` component is the default `App` component after creating a React app using `npx create-react-app ...` command, I suggest you not use another `App` name for other files in your project.

But if you want to use your `Navigation` component as the root component, you could try this:

##### Option 1:

index.js

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Navigation from "./Navigation ";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Navigation />,
  rootElement
);
```

Navigation.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Facilities from './Facilities'
import Room from './Room'
import Booking from './Booking'
import Contact from './Contact'
import App from '../App'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

const Navigation = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/facilities">
                    <Facilities/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/room">
                    <Room/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/contactus">
                    <Contact/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/bookingRoom">
                    <Booking/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/">
                    <App/>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}
export default Navigation
```

##### Option 2:

index.js: add `BrowserRouter as Router` from `react-router-dom` here

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Navigation /> {/* put the Navigation component here */}
  </Router>,
  rootElement
);
```

Navigation.js: delete `BrowserRouter as Router` from `react-router-dom` here

```js
return (
  <Switch>
      <Route path="/facilities">
          <Facilities/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/room">
          <Room/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/contactus">
          <Contact/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/bookingRoom">
          <Booking/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/">
          <App/>
      </Route>
  </Switch>
)
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, I had the same code as the option 2 and I tried to change my local host to one of the path but it didn't push the web to designated path, why is that ? localhost:3000/facilities

Comment: I have updated my answer (put ```Navigation``` component inside ```index.js```). please have a check

Answer (score 0):

Switch is not a link to a component, but a decision about what is to be rendered in this space.

Imagine it to be a (pseudo-code)

```
switch(path){ 
  case "path1": route(Component1); break; 
  case "path2": route(Component2); break;
  default: route("*"); break;
```

Therefore, put  in the  component (or at the highest level where you are branching based on path), and not navigation.

The way we have done (with react-bootstrap) in our apps is this way:

```
// App.js
import Navigation from "./Navigation";

import Facilities from "./Facilities" .. and so on

const App = ({}) => {
  return 
    <Navigation />
    <Switch> 
      <Route path="/facilities" component={Facilities}/>
      <Route path="/rooms" component={Rooms}/>
    </Switch>
}

// Navigation.js
import Link from "react-bootstrap/Link";

const Navigation = () => {
    <div>
      <Link to="/facilities"/>
      <Link to="/rooms"/>
    </div>
   
}
```